# how to make the material UI expansion panels open upwards when expanded instead expanding downwards?

Tags: accordion, material-ui

**Problem:**

- Upon expanding `expansion-panel`, it should expand upwards to show more info rather than expanding down which makes user to scroll down again.

Comment: I know it's bit too late but, you can still review my answer. (for angular material component)

Answer (score 8):

If you are using **[Angular Material Component's Expansion Panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview)**,
then you can use the following `css` for making the `expansion-panel` content to be present above the `mat-expansion-panel-header` in `styles.css` file.

```
.mat-expansion-panel {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.mat-expansion-panel-header {
  order: 2;
}
```

**[StackBlitz - Angular Material Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expansion-panel-open-from-down?file=styles.scss)**

**Update 1 :** **[React's Material UI Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/23q4r7rl4y)**

Comment: Would like to try as it is css way of doing. But I am using react's material UI by Google

Comment: In that case i have to see the DOM structure generated by the react material UI, if its same then it can be handled using css. If possible please share a small demo of react expansion panel.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar for  react's material UI https://codesandbox.io/s/l924p5l3lq

Comment: @contactdummy please see the updated answer for react material ui.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar - sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the updated answer. I have an issue related to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000095/material-ui-expand-panel-doesnt-shrink-the-above-div).  can you please have a look and tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: @contactdummy yes, what you have asked is completely a new question, my answer is only for the expansion panel component( for angular material, and react ui). And the demo is working fine in the updated code. So please use this demo to reach your goal, and if the answer is helpful, please upvote. Thank you.

Comment: You are a life saver, I would vote up 100 times if I could.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont mind panel moving header upwards after expantion, you could dock whole expansion panel / accordeon to bottom and use absolute positioning.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b11huf?embed=1&file=app/expansion-overview-example.css

However keep in mind that panel title, header and description order is important for correct displaying expansion panel and displaying just header at the bottom all the times is going to be painfull. Good Luck.