# Material UI - Expand Panel doesn't shrink the above div

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-ui

**Scenario :**

- I am using leaflet and React-table as one component.
- I have two div one below the another.
- The first div is leaflet map
  and the second div is react-table.
- The second div has Expansion
  Panels inside panel it has react-table.

**Issue :**

- The issue here is when I
  expand the panel it taking more than 100% of parent height. 
  It should
  shrink the first div to 60% and second div to 40% when I expand the
  panel.

**ISSUE**
[image] 
**Expected Output** - below image
[image]
[Running Code - Editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/qltfaj-hrbvbv)

Comment: The `div#map` has a hard-coded height of `93vh`, specified in `leaflet.js`. If you want it to shrink, you need to override that accordingly.

Comment: your code is not working..

Comment: @GauravRana Please check now.

Comment: The map container has  fixed width of 90vh. Therefore, it takes 90% of the view port.

Answer (score 0):

Add min-height for iframe as in below. You can add min-height according to your requirement.

```
<pre>
    iframe{min-height:300px;}
</pre>
```