# how to make the React material-UI Expansion Panel open upwards?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312373/how-to-make-the-material-ui-expansion-panels-open-upwards-when-expanded-instead) but it doesn't work in ReactJs.
how to make the Expansion Panel open upwards in ReactJs Material-Ui?

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this example for react. hope it helps you:

```
import React from 'react';
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import ExpansionPanel from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel';
import ExpansionPanelSummary from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelSummary';
import ExpansionPanelDetails from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelDetails';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
    },
    heading: {
        fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
        fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular,
    },
}));

export default function SimpleExpansionPanel() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <ExpansionPanel>
                <ExpansionPanelSummary
                    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon/>}
                    aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                    id="panel1a-header"
                >
                    <Typography className={classes.heading}>Expansion Panel 1</Typography>
                </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                    <Typography>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex,
                        sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
                    </Typography>
                </ExpansionPanelDetails>
            </ExpansionPanel>
            <ExpansionPanel>
                <ExpansionPanelSummary
                    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon/>}
                    aria-controls="panel2a-content"
                    id="panel2a-header"
                >
                    <Typography className={classes.heading}>Expansion Panel 2</Typography>
                </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                    <Typography>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex,
                        sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
                    </Typography>
                </ExpansionPanelDetails>
            </ExpansionPanel>
            <ExpansionPanel disabled>
                <ExpansionPanelSummary
                    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon/>}
                    aria-controls="panel3a-content"
                    id="panel3a-header"
                >
                    <Typography className={classes.heading}>Disabled Expansion Panel</Typography>
                </ExpansionPanelSummary>
            </ExpansionPanel>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[Source](https://material-ui.com/components/expansion-panels/)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it open downwards. I want `<ExpansionPanelDetails>` open upwards. I mean something like this :  [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expansion-panel-open-from-down?file=styles.scss)

Comment: @SamNickson, I checked material ui expansion panel and did not find anything that open upwards. we need to customize it to avail this behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I did too but couldn't find anything. Maybe we have to solve it in another way.