# Material UI - Expansion panel must expand upwards which is in footer so that users dont need to scroll down

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have gone through few other answers but no solution yet. Whats the problem is, I have added expansion panel in footer. So when I scroll down the webpage and click on expansion icon on footer it move downwards and again we need to scroll down to see the whole content. Any help would be much appriciated.

Comment: Hii we will need some code sample your tried...because it could be from many reasons....so please show us what your tried and hopefully we will help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just tried using normal expansion panel from Material ui. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312373/how-to-make-the-material-ui-expansion-panels-open-upwards-when-expanded-instead?rq=1 this is the problem I am facing.